How to prevent Frontend Sorting of a CPT from effecting ACF Field group order in admin?
With the free version of ACF, I created a CPT, taxonomy and field group. On the frontend, I wanted to display the CPT by Alphabetical order of the Title so I wrote a query and put it in functions.php. The issue I'm having trouble  solving  is the query  is also alphabetizing the ACF fields in the admin, which I don't want. Any help is much appreciated.
    if( !is_admin())  {
// Sort All Vendors by Title
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'sorting_archives' );
function sorting_archives( $wp_query ) {
 
    if (is_post_type_archive( 'vendor' ) || is_tax()) {
    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $wp_query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
  
    return $wp_query;
  }
}



Why don't you add the sorting to your actual wp_Query?

Pat, thank you, works great and I learned something!
